# How to take intersection of 3d graphics for 3d printing

Tags: graphics3d, 3d-printing

The following two-lobed blob is the union of two spheres, and it appears (?) that I can `Export[]` it to STL for 3d printing:

```
blob = Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0,0,0}, 1], Sphere[ {0,0,0.5}, 1]}]
```

How would I create the *intersection* instead of the union?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using geometric regions:

```
DiscretizeRegion[
 RegionIntersection[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1], Ball[{0, 0, 0.5}, 1]],
 MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001
];

Export["blob.stl", %];
Import["blob.stl"]
```

[image: reimported region]